Why can any user access to my UAuth app that is in test mode?
I am building an app that uses Google OAuth 2.0 for user authentication. The app should only allow access to users registered as test users in the Google Cloud OAuth consent screen, which is currently set to "Testing" mode. Despite this, unregistered users (emails not listed as test users) are still able to log in successfully, which should not happen.
The app correctly uses OAuth Client ID and Client Secret, and the redirect_uri mismatch issue has been resolved. I have verified that the OAuth consent screen is in Testing mode and have added test users, but unregistered users can still access the app.
Here's what i alredy tried:

Testing Mode: I verified that the app is in testing mode in Google Cloud Console.
Test Users List: I added test users to the OAuth consent screen and expected only those users to be allowed access.
Cache and Sessions: I tested the app in incognito mode to avoid session issues.
IAM Permissions: I checked if unregistered users were able to log in due to their role in the Google Cloud project (owner/editor) but found no issues there.
Client ID Check: I ensured the app is using the correct OAuth Client ID linked to the consent screen in Testing mode.

However, unregistered users can still log in, which is unexpected. I expected unregistered users to be blocked from accessing the app.

See this comment (and the remainder of the thread) on Google's Issue Tracker
